# How to interpret or decode the Hostdata column from Teradata error table

Tags: teradata

The use case is that, there is an Informatica Cloud mapping which loads from SQL Server to Teradata database. If there any failures during the run time of the mapping then that mappings writes all the failed rows to a table in Teradata database. The key column in this error table is `HOSTDATA` which I assume. I am trying to decode the `HOSTDATA` column so that if a similar ETL failure happens in the production then it would be helpful in identifying the root cause much quickly. By default `HOSTDATA` is a column of type VARBYTES.

To decode the `HOSTDATA` column, converted the column to `ASCII` and `Base 16` format. None of them made any use.

Then tried the below from the [Teradata forum](https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/tools/convert-hostdata-to-actual-record-from-error-table).

Then tried to extract the data from the error table using a `BTEQ` script. For that the data is being exported into a .err file and it is being loaded back into the Teradata database using a `fastload` script. Fastload is unable to load the data because there is no specific delimiter for the data. There data in the .err file looks gibberish. Snapshot of the data from the .err file:
[image]

My end goal is to interpret the `Hostdata` column in a more human readable way. Any suggestions in this direction are also welcome.

Comment: It's my understanding that what you are seeing is the buffer returned by the ODBC driver (sql server in this case) dumped into the err table. My guess, and I don't have an answer here, is that in order to shred this thing into human readable you would to treat this file as an odbc buffer using the ODBC standard and parse your way through the thing byte by byte. I don't know that a tool/library already exists so you don't have to dig through ODBC standards documentation and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Check out the Error Table Extractor command [twbertbl](https://docs.teradata.com/r/G4kxgNoyXX8P5vWrFMmibA/XC1Aat52H01FTBRO~Vwbew)

Comment: btw - from the screenshot I would say this load used FORMATTED record format.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I will explore more about twbertbl. Thanks @Fred.

Comment: @Fred, you can post it as an answer (add few details if you wanted to) so that I can choose it. :)

Comment: I didn't get the FORMATTED record format. In the BTEQ used for extracting the error table I didn't use any formatting options. Can you explain me clearly what are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error Table Extractor command [twbertbl](https://docs.teradata.com/r/G4kxgNoyXX8P5vWrFMmibA/XC1Aat52H01FTBRO%7EVwbew) which is part of "Teradata Parallel Transporter Base" software is designed to extract and format `HOSTDATA` from the error table VARBYTE column.

Based on the screenshot in your question, I suspect you will need to specify FORMATTED as the record format option for twbertbl (default is DELIMITED).